# Date picker and time picker not working properly (https://material-ui-next.com/demos/pickers/)

Tags: material-ui

Date picker and time picker not working properly. On desktop the calendar pop up won't show at all, work only in mobile. on Firefox, not show anything.

https://material-ui-next.com/demos/pickers/

Material-UI 1.0 beta.18

Answer (score 0):

This pickers are native browser implementation, so for the any os, any device it would be different, somewhere they doesnt implemented at all. So I suggest you use some libriry that implements that pickers for you. One of them (really awesome one) is [material-ui-pickers](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/material-ui-pickers)